# Why does my RegEx gives me only one element instead of the complete group in Java?

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, regex-group

I am new here and this is my first post. I'am also new to Java and RegEx. So...

I am working in Java and writing a RegEx to match phone numbers in a chat with this format: `+XXX (XXX) XXX XXXX` Written in numbers and/or in words.

This is my regex:

`"\\+?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){1,3}?[._\\-]? \\(?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3}\\)?[._\\-]? (zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3}[._\\-]?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){4}";`

Then using the method `.group()` to print the complete match and it works fine but if I want to print every different group with this loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= match.groupCount(); i++) {
    if (match.group(i) != null) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + match.group(i));
    }
}
```

then it prints ONLY JUST ONE DIGIT (OR WORD) of every group.

Why is that? And what do I have to do to print every element of every group?

I've also tried this regex

`"\\+?(zero{1,3}|uno{1,3}|due{1,3}|tre{1,3}|quattro{1,3}|cinque{1,3}|sei{1,3}|sette{1,3}|otto{1,3}|nove{1,3}|\\d{1,3})?[._\\-]?\\(?(zero{3}|uno{3}|due{3}|tre{3}|quattro{3}|cinque{3}|sei{3}|sette{3}|otto{3}|nove{3}|\\d{3})\\)?[._\\-]?(zero{3}|uno{3}|due{3}|tre{3}|quattro{3}|cinque{3}|sei{3}|sette{3}|otto{3}|nove{3}|\\d{3})[._\\-]?(zero{4}|uno{4}|due{4}|tre{4}|quattro{4}|cinque{4}|sei{4}|sette{4}|otto{4}|nove{4}|\\d{4})";`

...and also this one:

`"\\+?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d{1,3})?[._\\-]?\\(?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d{3})\\)?[._\\-]?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d{3})[._\\-]?(zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d{4})";`

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your groups [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471) `(?: ... )` and then wrap them into capturing ones. Something like:

```
"\\+?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){1,3}?)[._\\- ]?\\(?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3})\\)?[._\\- ]?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3})[._\\- ]?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){4})";
```

Reasoning: if group matched multiple times only last occurrence is captured.

Also, I've put spaces into symbol classes of delimiters.

Comment: Thx! I works now.

This is my final regex:

"(\\+?(?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){1,3})?[._\\-]?(\\(?(?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3}\\)?)[._\\-]?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){3})[._\\-]?((?:zero|uno|due|tre|quattro|cinque|sei|sette|otto|nove|\\d){4})";

I appreciate your help. :)